# Google Sheets Disable Formula ( or display text instead of formula on google sheets api call )

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

i am aware that formula are started with **'='** in google sheets

but i want to change that ( which i dont think is possible ) or **disable the formulas**

the reason i want to do that is , i have a **300+ encrypted codes** and few of them start with '=' ( the reason it starts with **'=' is the code is more 50,000+ letters** ..so eventually i had to divide it )

**MY PROBLEM**

i send request to google sheets api (return json value) and at that time i receive **#ERROR!** which is not what i want....and the reason for this is **FORMULA PARSE ERROR** , what i want is whether there is a **way to disable '=' the formula**..or to change the **#ERROR!** to the original text **when the sheets api is called ( json format )**( the original text is "**=xxxxxxxxxxxx**" )

( i know that i can **refactor and and a extra letter before '=' to prevent it** ... this is **last option** i am left with **if there is no way to disable the formula thing**)

Comment: Not possible, the whole point of the "=" sign is so you can make use of already known formulas or custom formulas in Google Sheets, you should analyze what you are currently doing and try to make it through a different way as what you want won't even be considered as a feature request for Google.

Comment: okay thanks ...will change the way the code is stored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possibility of disabling `"="` on Google Sheets will pretty much prevent the usage of formulas and custom formulas on the service, which will pretty much defeat the whole point of Google Sheets, due to this there is no current way of disabling formulas on a sheet. As mentioned, this type of feature won't be even considered as a feature request for the service.